# What is the quantity "risk" in survival analysis?

Tags: survival

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_ratio)

> ... the hazard ratio is a relative measure of effect and tells us nothing about **absolute risk**.

What is the definition of "absolute risk"  in survival analysis? Does it depend on time? Is it the value of the survival function at some time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The "absolute risk" is the events per unit time divided by the number of individuals susceptible to the event under observation. It is specifically *not* the value of S(t). During periods of no risk the S(t) will remain constant.

Request for an authority: This is what I find in my epidemiology text:

"Risk is the probability of an individual developing a given disease or experiencing a health status change over a specified period (conditinal on the individuals not dying from any other cause during that period.)

Notice that this authority (Kleinbaum, Kupper and Morgenstern's "Epidemiologic Research", 1982) specifies a time interval but specifically does not convert it to a rate. So they would prefer that risk be specified as a proportionate change in the the disease free population over a specified interval, but would not express it as a rate as I suggested. The Wikipedia section on absolute risk reduction is clearly using a difference in proportions over a specified interval (e.g. 5 years) as well. Rates, which KK&M distinguish from risk, on the other hand can be thought of as approaching the instantaneous rate of change as the interval is minimized.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give some reference for your definition?

Comment: That is correct.  Risk = probability, rate = slope or first derivative of something.

Comment: As I know you know, "sometimes" rate = (dS(t)/dt)/S(t).